# How to check if two conditions have been met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to have my player walk onto a GameObject and if they are on that object and they press the space key show a debug log.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
   if (other.gameObject.tag == "Level_1" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
   {
        Debug.Log("Both Conditions Reached");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you advise what the problem with your current code is?

Comment: In this code, the spacebar would have to be down when the object hits the collider. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Yes what is your issue? Are you just missing the closing curly brace for the if statement?

Comment: @wakeel This isn't a compilation issue. The question is poorly phrased, but the most likely error is detailed in the first answer.The missing brace is most likely the result of copy/past from source to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only trigger if they were holding down the space bar as they entered the object. You would do better to check if they were currently colliding with the object when the spacebar is pressed. (or do the check for both in Update)

Call this in your player object:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
   if (other.gameObject.tag == "Level_1") {
        player.isInside = true;
   }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
   if (other.gameObject.tag == "Level_1") {
        player.isInside = false;
   }
}
```

And use this to check for the spacebar:

```
 public void Update() {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && player.isInside == true) {
        Debug.Log("Both Conditions Reached");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'd probably replace `foo` with something like `isInside` or whatever, but otherwise good. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated :)